# problems in default constructor with try/catch block

Tags: scala

I wrote a program with Scala.
In a default constructor I have these lines.

```
private val url = new URL("http://www.  **  .xml")   //  throws  UnknownHostException
private val conn = url.openConnection
private val doc = XML.load(conn.getInputStream)
```

As you know if you have Internet communication problems may be thrown Exception.

I tried several ways to write these lines in  try/catch block .
But every time it shows me other compilation errors elsewhere in the class, in places where I use these variables.

Of course I wrote them inside a block, I defined the variables as public.

Can someone write me an example of how to do it correctly?

I might not be specific enough, but I did not know what exactly to explain because I do not know where exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pattern matching](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120) for the try/catch block is the idiomatic way to approach this in Scala.

```
import java.net.URL
import java.net._
import scala.xml.XML
try{
  val url = new URL("http://www. ** .xml")
  val conn = url.openConnection 
  val doc = XML.load(conn.getInputStream)
}catch{
  case uhe:UnknownHostException => println(uhe)
}
```

Comment: i try 
But I have problems compiling where I use doc

Comment: Then you have to make `doc` available outside of the scope of the `try` block. The quick and dirty way to do this is to initialize it like this `var doc:Elem = null` then it gets reassigned in the try block and is accessible outside of it. Note using `Option` in Scala is preferable to `null`.

Comment: @user1957061, if you find this answer useful, feel free to [follow the local customs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and *upvote* it by clicking on the up arrow on its left side. Moreover, if an answer solved your problem, you may *accept* it by clicking on the check mark icon.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an improvement:

```
import java.net.URL
import java.net._
import scala.xml.XML

val doc =
  try {
    val url = new URL("http://www.xxx.yyy/XYZZY.xml")
    val conn = url.openConnection
    Right(XML.load(conn.getInputStream))
  }
  catch {
    case ex: Exception => Left(ex)
  }

doc match {
  case Right(xmlDoc) => // Do stuff with the doc XML
  case Left(ex)      => // Do error stuff with the exception
}
```